# Unity PropertyDrawer applied to children who have own PropertyDrawer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drawer, unity-editor

I've a series of classes:

```
public class A<T> : ScriptableObject {}

public class B : A<int> { }

public class C : A<float> { }

public class D<T> : A<T> { }

public class E : D<int> { }
```

And I've two Drawers:

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(A<>), true)]
public class ADrawer : PropertyDrawer { }

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(D<>), true)]
public class DDrawer : PropertyDrawer { }
```

The problem is that ADrawer is applied to E objects too instead of DDrawer also if I make

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(E), true)]
public class EDrawer : PropertyDrawer { }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solution is: put the two Drawers in different namespaces.
Example:

```
namespace FakeNamespace.Drawers
{
    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(A<>), true)]
    public class ADrawer : PropertyDrawer { }
}

namespace FakeNamespace.Drawers.Others
{
    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(D<>), true)]
    public class DDrawer : PropertyDrawer { }
}
```